# what installs files to Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v2.0\Assemblies?

Tags: model-view-controller

My new dev machine is lacking files in this location

c:\program files (x86) \Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v2.0\Assemblies

My mvc project cannot start because its missing a deployment.dll but I don't know what install I need to run. I've run all 3 mvc's and almost everything in platfom installer

Comment: Do you have tried with asp.net web pages 2.0 come with Visualstudio/ Webmatrix. If your system don't have them. try to install them through Web plateform installer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i know, ASP.NET Web Pages v2.0 use with MVC 4. For MVC 3 use v1.0